# What is the working directory for a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I have set up a Shiny server on Linux at this path

```
/srv/shiny-server/myApp
```

This app calls data, which are stored (though a symbolic link) in

```
/srv/shiny-server/myApp/data/input.txt
```

and opened with the relative path

```
"data/input.txt"
```

When calling this app :

```
my_ip_adress:3838/myApp
```

It breaks, not finding the data. I guess it is a path issue, but the idea of a R package is self-containment, so this relative path should be fine.

I have tried with the full path:

```
"/srv/shiny-server/myApp/data/input.txt"
```

but get

```
Warning: Error in fread: File '/srv/shiny-server/myApp/data/input.txt' does not exist. Include one or more spaces to consider the input a system command.
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried `/srv/shiny-server/myApp/inst/app/`?

Comment: Difficult to analyse: But have you tried `addResourcePath()` already?

Comment: More info : I think the reason is this input.txt file is stored on another directory, where Shiny may not have the permission to read. If I replace the links by the real files, it works.